# Where is CampaignInfluence object?

Tags: api, release, winter17, campaign-influence

With the release of [Winter '17](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_sales_features_core_campaigns.htm), API access to Campaign Influence is opened. But when I tried to access campaign influence using the Developer Console or Data Loader it is showing **CampaignInfluenceModel** but not CampaignInfluence.

**Developer Console SOQL Error**

> sObject type 'CampaignInfluence' is not supported.

**Data loader screenshot**

[image]

I'm wondering where is CampaignInfluence, it is still not there. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is very weird -- I enabled Customizable Campaign Influence in two orgs (Dev Edition and a Sandbox) and in both cases, `CampaignInfluence` is not an entity recognized by Workbench or APEX

Comment: Exactly, I wonder where is it and how can we get it to show itself in our orgs. They say that is it **generally available** but it is not. By the way, documentation is still missing related to this object. :-)

Comment: see doc: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_campaigninfluence.htm?search_text=campaigninfluence

Comment: Anybody got any update on this?

Comment: So the following doc, claims that you can [query(), retrieve(), update(), upsert()] however this is not true at all, from what I can tell... I even double checked and it's enabled via API in the Campaign Influence > Campaign Influence Settings. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_campaigninfluence.htm?search_text=campaigninfluence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost forgot about this question, I created a case with Salesforce last year and for once got something helpful from them. Given below is the solution that I got from Salesforce support which worked

1. Navigate to the User detail page and scroll down to the Related list Permission Set License Assignments and assign either CRM User or Sales User license to the User.
2. Create a permission set with the "Campaign Influence" permission

   - To create Permission Set: Click **Setup | Manage Users | Permission Sets | Enable permission** "Campaign Influence" or another option is to create a Custom Profile with the permission "Campaign Influence"
   - After Enabling the Campaign Influence, Click on Manage Assignment button and select your name to assign it to or other users you want to have that permission set.

Some links which would explain the steps in detail.

- [Campaign Influence Related List not available on Opportunities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Why-Campaign-influence-related-list-is-not-available-on-Opportunities&language=en_US&type=1)
- [Set Up Customizable Campaign Influence](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_sales_features_core_campaign_influence2_setup.htm)